# Prove the following equality involving $f'(0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

I was doing the following problem:

$f$ is an analytic function defined in a neighborhood of $0$, and $f'(0)\neq 0$. Show that 
$$\frac{1}{f'(0)}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{1}{f(z)-f(0)}dz,$$
provided that $r>0$ is sufficiently small.

I was trying to use the Cauchy integral formula for the inverse of $f$, but it doesn't seem to give the desired integral. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the residue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function

$$g(z)=\begin{cases}
\frac{z}{f(z)-f(0)} &,z\ne0\\\\\frac1{f'(0)}&,z=0
\end{cases}
$$

is analytic on $|z|<r$ for sufficiently small values of $r$.

Hence, Cauchy's Integral Formula guarantees that for any such sufficiently small $r$

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=r}\frac{1}{f(z)-f(0)}\,dz&=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=r}\frac{g(z)}{z}\,dz\\\\
&=g(0)\\\\
&=\frac1{f'(0)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: from your definition, it would seem that $\frac1{f(z)-f(0)}=\frac{g(z)}z$, not $\frac1{zg(z)}$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks.  I've edited.